# Rails - seed data dynamically from with the result of API calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm fairly new to Ruby on Rails and I'm having some trouble designing the db.
So right now I have a table with about 100 records, populated from seeds.rb. Now I want to use this data to make an API call per record to get more information and I want to update the row with this new info I got from the API call. Is this possible in any way?

For example if I have this in seeds.rb,

```
Example.create(fruit: 'orange')
```

and I want to call this API which gives me the colour of this fruit,

```
color = api.param(fruit)
```

and I want to update the record,

```
fruit:'orange', color:'orange'
```

like so.

Can this be done as part of the seeding procedure? My vision is to run this migration every month or so to prevent outdated data.
Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confused with your terminology.

A migration is a change to the [database schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_schema), not the data itself.

[Database seeding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_seeding) is the initial seeding of a database with data and should only be done once in the beginning of development (or when an application in development is transferred to another developer).

What you need is not a migration, but a scheduled job that runs a rake task that calls your external API and updates your local database.

Create a rake task (this is an old but still relevant [tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/66-custom-rake-tasks)) that calls your external API, gets the data, and updates the database. Then schedule this task to run at the interval you require, you can use the [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever) to do it.